# Append .php json to javascript

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this json result from my site 'www.example.com/jsonresult.php'

```
{
    1:  {
      item_id: "Balls",
      item2: "2",
      item3: "3",
      item4: "4"
   }
}
```

How do i append it in my jquery mobile javascript at

```
$.ajax({
                    url: forecastURL,
                    jsonCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(json) {
                        console.log(json);                        
                        $("#current_temp").html('here');
                        $("#current_summ").html('and here');    

                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        console.log(e.message);
                    }
                });`
```

please help, thanks.

Comment: Use `ajax` to get `json` or `iframe`?

Comment: **WHAT DO YOU WANT THERE??()**

Comment: @ekky008 The result you got in json is a datastructure. What do you want to put into HTML?

Comment: use : `$("#ul").load("http://www.example.com/jsonresult.php")`

Comment: let say i wanted to extract 'Balls', i use,  
`$("#ul").html(id.item_id);`
Dint return any result.
Sorry for the caps :p @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
$("#ul").html(myvar['1'].item_id);
```

Have a look at [this JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gxja74/)